# Github actions: how to configure runner to use a specific image

Tags: github-actions, github-actions-runners, github-actions-workflows

My project currently fails on the `windows-2022` runner. It's configured via a Github worfklow (excerpt):

```yaml
jobs:
  test:
    runs-on: windows-2022
```

I can see that the last successful run took place on the `win22/20220529` image of the runner. I'd like to run the tests on past releases, to find out where exactly they started failing. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, once GitHub/Microsoft push out a new version of the image, that's it. There is no way to request an older version of that image. These runners are quite large and they keep a number of VMs on standby in Azure to pick up the job. The runners aren't provisioned on the fly just for you.

You can build the older version of the runner yourself using the scripts in the repository by checking out the older commit and then use that image to setup a self-hasted runner in Azure or locally yourself.

Comment: That's a shame - it would be quite useful to find the enviromnment change that caused the project to break.